# How to wait for an attribute to change

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress, overflow

I have a DOM element in ag-grid

```html
<div class="ag-floating-bottom" ref="eBottom" role="presentation" 
  style="min-height:0px;height:0px; display:none;overflow-y:scroll;">
```

And when I select some filter from some column the grid is boil down to few rows only and this `overflow-y` attribute get changed to `overflow-y:hidden` from scroll

```html
<div class="ag-floating-bottom" ref="eBottom" role="presentation" 
  style="min-height:0px;height:0px; display:none;overflow-y:hidden;">
```

I want to put wait on this attribute overflow-y till it get change to `hidden`

Answer (score 3):

You can check what the element declares using the "have.css" assertion, something like this:

```js
cy.get('div[ref="eBottom"]')
  .should('have.css', 'overflow-y', 'hidden')  // retry until scroll becomes hidden
```

Answer (score -1):

.should will retry until the condition is met and you can also pass timeout in get if it takes longer than your default timeout

`cy.get('div[ref="eBottom"]', {timeout: 90000}).should('have.css', 'overflow-y', 'hidden')`